# PHP Ejabberd Handshaking

Tags: php, ejabberd, publish-subscribe

I am creating a social networking site where I want users to chat and receive live notifications like Facebook, I tried searching for possible solutions and found ejabberd's pubsub module (I am using ejabberd for chatting), so my option is to create some sort of pubsub service for that or second solution I have in mind is that upon entering a feed into mysql db, I send some sort of special message to user using ejabberd, for that I want to use jaxl php library, I tried it and it works just fine if you send message from javascript->php->ejabberd, but dosen't work if I try to send messages using only php.

Please tell me if my approaches are right or there is a better solution for that.

Comment: if you want to create a facebook copy and you don't know where to start you are completly mad

Comment: No, I do know where to start, but I need some help with this issue.

Comment: I don't need school, please don't comment if you can't help, if you are experienced then please help, else I assume we both have to go to school *KID*

Answer (score 0):

I have used JsJAC will great success.  Skip PHP all together and make this a client-side operation.

http://blog.jwchat.org/jsjac/

Comment: I am using jsjac for client side, but I have a cron job running in the back which will push notifications to user via ejabberd.